# Laravel 5.2 and Valet - unable to send email - Unable to find the socket transport "plain"

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Valet and Laravel 5.2. When I try to trigger sending an email, I receive this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269:
Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io 
[Unable to find the socket transport "plain" - did you forget to enable 
it when you configured PHP? #1]
```

**.Env file:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=whatTheyGaveMe
MAIL_PASSWORD=whatTheyGaveMe
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=PLAIN
```

**Mail function:**

```
public function sendClinicEmail($id, $emailType, $data)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    Mail::queue('emails.clinic.' . $emailType . '', ['user' => $user, 'data' => $data], 
        function ($m) use ($user, $data) {

        $brandName = Config::get('brand.name');

        $m->from('hello@app.com', '' . $brandName . '');

        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject($data['subject']);
    });
}
```

How can I resolve this please? No matter what type of AUTH that I use, it still returns the same error, just relating to the AUTH type. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This encryption value set to plain, probably is not valid in this situation. You can try this:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Or set it to NULL

Comment: I tried all authentication types and they all return that error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this error in or after 2018, and finding this on google, my fix was to change the host from mailtrap.io to smtp.mailtrap.io. The reason for this change can be found here:
https://mailtrap.io/blog/2018-03-09-why-mailtrap-updated-its-smtp-host

Answer (score 0):

PLAIN - is an auth method, but you use it as MAIL_ENCRYPTION, just set there

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL
```

That should work fine.